# $L^p$ spaces are a set or a class?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume $X$ is a set measure space with positive measure $\mu$. Then the collection of all measurable functions from $X$ into the complex set $\mathbb{C}$ is a set or a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely a set. Indeed, the collection of all functions whatsoever from one set into another set is always itself a set: remember that every function from $A$ to $B$ is a subset of $A\times B$, and hence an element of the powerset $\mathcal{P}(A\times B)$. At this point all you need to do is build Cartesian products using the set-theoretic axioms, which is a good exercise.